# C# dictionary keeps changing the values into the last added value.

Tags: c#, dictionary, visual-studio-2015

When I try to add a new name and number from textboxes into a dictionary, and then try to add the content of the dictionary to a listBox all the previous entries are the same. Like if I add "Bob Johnson 42", "Jim Smith 33", "Peter White 21". When I put it in the ListBox it will apear as:
Peter White 21 
Peter White 21 
Peter White 21

What am I doing wrong? 
Here is the code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           String name = this.textBox1.Text;
           int testNumber = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
           submittedTests.Add(this.textBox1.Text, testNumber);

        foreach (var x in submittedTests)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(name + " " + testNumber);
        }

   }
```

Comment: You need to access `Key` and `Value` from your dictionary, currently you are accessing your local variables. `listBox1.Items.Add(x.Key + " " + x.Value);` should fix it

Answer (score 3):

You are using the values for `name` and `testnumber` from outside the loop

```
   foreach (var x in submittedTests)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(name + " " + testNumber);
    }
```

Should be

```
   foreach (var x in submittedTests)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(x.name + " " + x.testNumber);
    }
```

or if `submittedTests` is a dictionary:

```
foreach (var x in submittedTests)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(x.Key + " " + x.Value);
}
```

Comment: It should be `x.Key`, `x.Value`, since it is a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       String name = this.textBox1.Text;
       int testNumber = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
       submittedTests.Add(this.textBox1.Text, testNumber);

    foreach (var x in submittedTests)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(x.Key + " " + x.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
listBox1.Items.Add(name + " " + testNumber);
```

To

```
listBox1.Items.Add(x.Key + " " + x.Value);
```